# How to compare the value from two joins and based on sum value force the use of another value instead

Tags: sql, db2

thanks for any feedback in advance.

I have the following conundrum with this SQL script. I’m doing a read from a db2 server, and the script consists of three tables, but two of the tables are giving me an issue.

I have table 1, this table is the locations table. The table has two key columns, `PL_COUNT`, and `LOC_SYSID`. The `PL_COUNT` tells many how many plts fit into each location.

Table 2, this table is the inventory table, the table has only the `LOC_SYSID` among other fields, but the `LOC_SYSID` column is the key finding out how many plts are located in the location. To find how many plts are located in the location, I did a sum to determine how many plts are in each location using the `LOC_SYSID` to join. This worked perfect, but when the sum of the inventory table has more records returned than what the `PL_COUNT` can hold. The sum is incorrect I would like to instead force the script use the `PL_COUNT` value from the location table instead.

I tried a couple of things, but no luck. The approach was using a case and when the sum of the inventory table was > than `PL_CCOUNT` in location table, I would force the use of the `PL_COUNT` instead. However, the case approach did not work and I kept getting an error every time. At this point I’m out of ideas and do not know if this approach could work or not.

Once again, thanks for any feedback

```
            LOCATIONS TABLE 1
           |LOC_SYSID |PL_COUNT|whsesysid|
           |10001     |2       |1        |
           |10002     |2       |1        |
           |10003     |2       |1        |
           |10004     |2       |2        |
           |10005     |1       |2        |
           |10006     |1       |2        |


            INVENTORY TABLE 2
            PLT_SYSID |LOC_SYSID|whsesysid|
           |1         |10001    |1        |
           |2         |10001    |1        |
           |3         |10001    |1        |
           |4         |10002    |1        |
           |5         |10002    |1        |
           |6         |10002    |1        |
           |7         |10002    |1        |
           |8         |10003    |1        |                 
           |9         |10003    |1        |
           |10        |10003    |1        |
           |11        |10004    |2        |
           |12        |10005    |2        |
           |13        |10006    |2        |
           |14        |10006    |2        |
           |15        |10006    |2        |
           |16        |10006    |2        |                 



            SQL OUTPUT 
            whseSysId |whsename|availableFootprints |usedFootprints
           |1         |10001   |8                   |10              In this result it should be 8, but since ls1 has 3, ls2 has 4, and ls3 has 3              
           |2         |10002   |4                   |6               Same issue, this should be 4.
```

```sql
SELECT
  wh.WHSE_SYSID AS whseSysId,
  (SELECT
    SUM(loc.PL_COUNT)
  FROM ROOM rm
  INNER JOIN LOCATIONS loc
    ON rm.ROOM_SYSID = loc.ROOM_SYSID
  WHERE loc.PL_COUNT > 0
  AND rm.WHSE_SYSID = :whseSysId)
  AS availableFootprints,
  SUM(
  BIGINT(
  ROUND((SELECT
    SUM(CASE
      WHEN st.INVTRY_PALLET_STACK_SYSID IS NULL THEN 1
      ELSE 0.5
    END)
  FROM ROOM rm
  INNER JOIN LOCATIONS loc
    ON rm.ROOM_SYSID =
    loc.ROOM_SYSID
  INNER JOIN INVTRY_PALLET_DTL p
    ON loc.LOC_SYSID =
    p.LOC_SYSID
  LEFT JOIN INVTRY_PALLET_STACK st
    ON p.WHSE_SYSID = st.WHSE_SYSID
    AND (p.INB_LPN =
    st.MASTER_INB_LPN
    OR p.INB_LPN = st.INB_LPN)
  WHERE rm.WHSE_SYSID = :whseSysId), 0
  )
  )
  ) AS usedFootprints
FROM WHSE wh
WHERE wh.WHSE_SYSID = :whseSysId
GROUP BY wh.WHSE_SYSID,
         wh.WHSE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest "think joins first" (i.e. look for way to include the data via joins instead of using subqueries in a select clause).

This is how I would go about it. Leverage both the existing subqueries but push them into the FROM clause and to do this we need a way to join so both of them now GROUP BY rm.WHSE_SYSID so that the result can join to wh.WHSE_SYSID. Note because of this you don't need to use so many where clauses with the bind variable :whseSysId (the optimizer will sort this out for you).

Once you have moved all the data sourcing into the FROM clause then you just use the column aliases for the wanted case expression. Much simpler. (May also be faster.)

```
SELECT
      wh.WHSE_SYSID
    , wh.WHSE_NAME
    , loc.availableFootprints
    , rm.usedFootprints
    , case
          when rm.usedFootprints > loc.availableFootprints then loc.availableFootprints
          else rm.usedFootprints 
      end AS Whatever
FROM WHSE wh
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            rm.WHSE
          , SUM(loc.PL_COUNT) AS availableFootprints
      FROM ROOM rm
      INNER JOIN LOCATIONS loc ON rm.ROOM_SYSID = loc.ROOM_SYSID
      WHERE loc.PL_COUNT > 0
      GROUP BY rm.WHSE_SYSID
) loc ON wh.WHSE_SYSID = loc.WHSE_SYSID
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            rm.WHSE_SYSID
          , SUM(CASE
                  WHEN st.INVTRY_PALLET_STACK_SYSID IS NULL
                  THEN 1
                  ELSE 0.5 END) AS usedFootprints
      FROM ROOM rm
      INNER JOIN LOCATIONS loc ON rm.ROOM_SYSID = loc.ROOM_SYSID
      INNER JOIN INVTRY_PALLET_DTL p ON loc.LOC_SYSID = p.LOC_SYSID
      LEFT JOIN INVTRY_PALLET_STACK st ON p.WHSE_SYSID = st.WHSE_SYSID
            AND (p.INB_LPN = st.MASTER_INB_LPN OR p.INB_LPN = st.INB_LPN)
      GROUP BY rm.WHSE_SYSID
) rm ON wh.WHSE_SYSID = rm.WHSE_SYSID
WHERE wh.WHSE_SYSID = :whseSysId
;
```

I have used LEFT JOINS because I don't know your data. If either subquery, when joined to WHSE, might cause a NULL to occur because there is no joined row(s) then you may have to introduce COALESCE() into the case expression, *for example only*:

```
    , coalesce(case
          when rm.usedFootprints > loc.availableFootprints then loc.availableFootprints
          else rm.usedFootprints 
      end,0) AS Whatever
```

Comment: This example from above worked, but only for forcing the use of the 'loc.availableFootprints'. But I would still like be able to retrieve the same result but as a sum instead, with the sum I mean the sum of the 'loc.availableFootprints'. I think with this approach and some tweaking I can this to work. Thanks for the help